# Intent createChooser stop code not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

I had a code in pre-Marshmallow application that selected only some of the installed applications that implement the `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and the show a `Intent.createChooser` with only those. This is the full code:

```
Intent actionSendIntent = new Intent();
actionSendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
actionSendIntent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(actionSendIntent, 0);

List<Intent> shareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
if(!resInfos.isEmpty()){
    for(ResolveInfo res : resInfos){
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") ||
                packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana") ||
                packageName.contains("com.facebook.lite") ||
                packageName.contains("com.whatsapp")) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            shareIntents.add(intent);
        }
    }
}
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntents.remove(0), shareText);
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, shareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(chooserIntent, shareText));
```

This code does not work in Marshmallow and show Android System as the only available option... does anyone know why?

Comment: I'm surprised that code works anywhere. Do not put a chooser `Intent` inside a chooser `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, so... how should it be to make it work properly?

Comment: Get rid of one of those `createChooser()` calls. Probably it should be the second one, as IIRC the `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` goes on the `ACTION_CHOOSER` `Intent`, which is `chooserIntent`. Since `chooserIntent` is already a chooser `Intent`, you do not need to create a chooser on the chooser.